# ¿Como agregar comillas simples (') o dobles (") a una lista de strings en pascal?

Tags: delphi, pascal

Buenos días estoy tratando de armar una consulta para Firebird 2.5. La consulta que busco crear tiene que tener el siguiente formato:

```
Select *
From Clientes c
Where c.activo = 1 and c.cuit not in ("11-11111111","11-11111112",....hasta n codigos)
```

El siguiente procedimiento es el encargado de llenar la lista con los datos de una grilla:

```
function TfImportacionArchivoARBARetenPercep.fxListarClientesProveedoresNoEnGrilla(
  pboClientes: Boolean): WideString;
var
  slAux: TStringList;
  niCol, niI: Integer;
  wsAux : WideString;
  stTabla: String;
  qCliProv: TFXQuery;

begin
  wsAux := '';

  if pboClientes then
  begin
    niCol := 11;
    stTabla := 'Clientes'
  end
  else
  begin
    stTabla := 'Proveedores';
    niCol := 12;
  end;

  for niI := 1 to gDetalle.RowCount - 1 do
    if Trim(gDetalle.Cells[niCol, niI]) <> '' then
      wsAux := wsAux + iif((Trim(wsAux) = ''), '',  ',') + Trim(gDetalle.Cells[3, niI]);

  slAux :=  fxObtenerListaCondicionalesConsulta(wsAux );//esta funcion le da formato a la lista de strings


  try
    qCliProv.SQL.Text :=
      ' Select Codigo' + iif(pboClientes, Copy(stTabla, 0, 7), Copy(stTabla, 0, 9)) + ' As Codigo' +
      '   From ' + stTabla +
      '  Where Activo = 1 ';

    if slAux.Count > 0 then
      for niI := 0 to slAux.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if Trim(slAux.Strings[niI]) = '' then
          Continue;

        qCliProv.SQL.Add(
          '    And Cuit Not In (' +
          slAux.Strings[niI] + ')'  );
      end;

    qCliProv.Open;//el resto de codigo no es importante
```

Esta es la funcion que le da el formato a la lista de strings:

```
function TfImportacionArchivoARBARetenPercep.fxObtenerListaCondicionalesConsulta(
  pstClientes: WideString): TStringList;
var
  slAux, slAuxResultado: TStringList;
  niI, niLinea: Integer;
begin
  niLinea := 0;

  slAuxResultado := TStringList.Create;
  slAux := TStringList.Create;

  try
    slAuxResultado.Add('"');

    slAux.Delimiter := ',';
    slAux.DelimitedText := pstClientes;

    for niI := 0 to slAux.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if ((Frac(niI/100) = 0) and (nII <> 0)) then
      begin
        Inc(niLinea);
        slAuxResultado.Add('');
       end;

       slAuxResultado.Strings[niLinea] := slAuxResultado.Strings[niLinea] +
                                          iif((slAuxResultado.Strings[niLinea] = ''), '', ',' )  + slAux.Strings[niI];
    end;

    result := slAuxResultado;

  finally
    FreeAndNil(slAux);
  end;
end;
```

He intentando miles de cambios, pero no logro que la lista de strings quede con el formato necesario para realizar la consulta SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veo varios problemas con tu código:

- En Firebird, y en SQL en general, las cadenas de caracteres se encierran entre comillas simples <kbd>'</kbd>, y no comillas dobles.

  Además, cuando una cadena contiene una comilla simple, esta se *duplica* en la cadena, por ejemplo `D'blasio` se representa así:  `'D''blasio'`.

  La RTL de Delphi, en la unidad `SysUtils` tiene la función **[`QuotedStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.QuotedStr)** que realiza esta tarea.
- Agregas varias cláusulas `cui not in` al where, cuando la intención es claramente agregar solo una
- Cuándo estás recorriendo `gDetalle`, en el `if` evalúas una celda, pero a la cadena le agregas una celda distinta. Esto puede ser correcto, pero sin más información, huele a que podría no serlo.
- La clase `TStringList` puede devolver una lista separada por comas, que viene al caso para llenar los valores de la cláusula `not in ()`.

Simplificando las cosas y tomando en cuenta lo dicho, tu rutina podría reducirse a algo como esto:

```
function TfImportacionArchivoARBARetenPercep.fxListarClientesProveedoresNoEnGrilla(
  pboClientes: Boolean): WideString;
var
  niCol, niI: Integer;
  stTabla, stCampo: string;
  qCliProv: TFXQuery;
  ValoresNotIn: TStringList;
begin
  if pboClientes then
  begin
    niCol := 11;
    stTabla := 'Clientes'
    stCampo := 'Cliente';
  end
  else
  begin
    stTabla := 'Proveedores';
    stCampo := 'Proveedor';
    niCol := 12;
  end;

  ValoresNotIn := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for niI := 1 to gDetalle.RowCount - 1 do
      if Trim(gDetalle.Cells[niCol, niI]) <> '' then
        ValoresNotIn.Add(QuotedString(Trim(gDetalle.Cells[3, niI]));  //no estoy seguro si usar la celda [3, o la celda [niCol, que es la que se evalúa en el IF

    qCliProv.SQL.Text :=
      ' Select Codigo' + stCampo +
      '   From ' + stTabla +
      '  Where Activo = 1 ';
    if ValoresNotIn.Count > 0 then
      qCliProv.Add('   and cuit not in (' + ValoresNotIn.CommaText + ')';
  finally
    ValoresNotIn.Free;
  end;
  try
    qCliProv.Open;//el resto de codigo no es importante
```

Como ves, creo un `TStringList` auxiliar, en el que voy metiendo las cadenas que van dentro de los paréntesis en la cláusula SQL, de una vez con sus comillas (valiéndome de `QuotedStr`). Luego, si esta lista tiene algún valor, agrego una sola cláusula `not in ()` a la sentencia SQL, conteniendo todos los valores separados por comas.

Comment: Muy buena tu respuesta, me recontra sirvió, muchas gracias. Con respecto a la validación del if, valido que el código del cliente o proveedor sea distinto de vacío, si es true entonces le pido el CUIT que esta en la celda 3.